# Pythonic way to do two un-nested for loops as a list comprehension

Tags: loops, list-comprehension

I have two large loops to process that I'd rather do pythonically with a list comprehension. Is that possible?

Take:

```
males = ['a', 'b']
females = ['c', 'd']

for i in males:
    print(i)
for j in females:
    print(j)
```

What I want is something like:

```
[print(i), print(j) for i, j in males, females]
```

Result:

```
a
b
c 
d
```

Comment: `[print(i) for i in males+females]`. I won't call this "Pythonic way" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally not a good idea to use list comprehensions just for side effects. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).

I'd say your current version is the best way to do it. But as far as if it's possible...

```
for _ in map(print, males + females):
    pass
```

or

```
[print(x) for x in males + females]
```

or just a for loop

```
for x in males + females:
    print(x)
```